# How to write a unit test that classes implementing a contract should pass

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am not sure if this is a valid question. It is difficult when you have a question but do not know related terms to type into search. So my searches are not yielding any meaningful result. I just want to know if it is a thing to write a unit test that classes that implement a contract should pass.

For example I want to define the following contract:

```php
abstract class FooContract
{

    public function setup(): bool
    {
        // General setup code
    }

    abstract function run(): string;
}
```

A programmer can write a class named Baz which implements the contract thus:

```php
class Baz extends FooContract
{

    public function run(): string
    {
        // run code
    }
}
```

I want to give the programmer a choice to not have to write a full test every time she implements FooContract. So I want to give the following set of unit tests to the programmer of the class Baz:

```php
trait FooContractTest
{
    private function getInstanceOrFail()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'getInstance')) {
            if (($instance = $this->getInstance()) instanceof FooContract) {
                return $instance;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception('Define the method getInstance() in your test. You should then return an instance of FooContract under test from getInstance');
    }

    public function test_can_setup()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->getInstanceOrFail()->setup());
    }

    public function test_can_run()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('Done', $this->getInstanceOrFail()->run());
    }
}
```

I want the programmer of Baz to run the test as follows:

```php
class BazTest extends PHPUnit_TestCase
{
    use FooContractTest;

    public function getInstance()
    {
        return new Baz;
    }
}
```

My question is, is this a thing? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I’m not seeing what benefit your trait (which could just be a subclass, too) brings. An `instance of` check in general shouldn’t be needed because if they aren’t then they aren’t testing your contract. The trait also has a return string baked in. It seems like the test is just `$this->assertSame("Done", (new Baz)->run());` which isn’t hard to write from a test standpoint.

Comment: @ChrisHaas instanceof is useful here to help the programmer who is trying to test a wrong contract by mistake. Don't be caught up on the simplicity of my minimal working example;  in the battlefield, just imagine FooContractTest having 100 tests  with each test containing say 50 lines of codes including calls to subroutines, and 10 assertions. Now imagine having to rewrite such a tests every time you implement FooContract.

Comment: that information, specifically the complexity, should probably be added to the question because it is pretty relevant. If you can write code that helps someone test their code, I’d say that’s fine, as long as you don’t bend your base code too far to support the tests. One possible danger I see is that tests where “magic happens” could lead to broken things “but my tests all pass”.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I am not sure I got your last sentence.  But see, if your implementation of my contract passes my test for the contract, then I am guaranteeing that whatever magic that happens is a good magic.

Comment: Going back to your simplified example, imagine it being a class called `AbstractTask` and someone implements a `DatabaseUpdateTask` that extends it. That custom class has a custom method called `LoadItems()` that loads an internal array and the creator of the class expects it to be called before `run()` and there’s obviously no way for your test harness to know about that method, it just calls `run()` which processes an empty array. You and I’d _expect_ that code’s creator to know all this, but if the test-writer is a different person it could get lost in the magic.

Comment: I’m not saying your code is wrong or bad, you just asked for some thoughts on it, and I just wanted to point it out. It is absolutely possible your implementors wouldn’t have anything like this and it just works exactly as you expect, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I understand that you are giving your opinion to help and for that I am glad. Your example is assuming that the contract may not me honored; in that case the test will fail; the test does not need to know about any non-contracted method. I have this working fine in a project. I am interested in knowing if people do it in a different way.

Comment: my sample actually shows the “contract” as being honored but also doing/requiring more. Adding those methods “fulfills the contract”, but there’s no way for your code to know/test about any prerequisites. My fictional example defaults to an empty array until `LoadItems` is called. You’d hope I’d do that in `getInstance`, but it might not be obvious. I guess you could add additional methods like `setupInstance` and `tearDownInstance` that default to no-ops to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to provide a set of reusable tests. A trait containing common tests seems like a fair solution to me.

Rename the trait to make it more clear what its purpose is e.g. `CommonFooContractTests`, `FooContractCommonTests`. Remember, naming it with a postfix "Test" may cause problems in PHPUnit because it may think it's a test. Using words like "Common" and "Tests" makes it a bit more clear.

I would make the instance dependency a requirement in the trait by using an abstract method with an expected return type  and rename the instance getter to be trait specific factory method.

```
trait FooContractCommonTests
{
    abstract public function createFooContract(): FooContract;

    public function testCanSetup(): void
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->createFooContract()->setup());
    }
}
```

If you can't use a return a type, then use a test to evaluate the expected type and make all other tests depend on it:

```
trait FooContractCommonTests
{
    abstract public function createFooContract();

    public function testGetInstanceIsInstanceOfFooContract(): void
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(FooContract::class, $this->createFooContract());
    }

    /**
     * @depends testGetInstanceIsInstanceOfFooContract
     */
    public function testCanSetup(): void
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->createFooContract()->setup());
    }
}
```

Other than that I don't see much wrong with using a common tests trait, even with the way you already implemented it using `getInstanceOrFail`, it's not so bad, though I do think the abstract method with expected return type is the cleanest and most clear implementation.